# Proper response to "Let's meet..."

Tags: verbs, questions, expression-choice, test

What's the proper response to this

> Linda: "Let's meet outside the library."
>   Lucy: "____"

A. Is 6.30 all right?

B. Yes, let's do it

C. How about meeting again?

D. I'd like to go to the library

A and B both sound fine to me but which one is correct? :D

Comment: I don't understand, are you suggesting C and D are also possible responses?

Comment: B is the answer the test wants you to reply with. Linda is making a suggestion to Lucy. First, Lucy needs to agree if she wants to meet outside the library. A is ambiguous, (OK, I'm being persnickety here but test books are all like this) is it 06.30 in the morning or 18.30 in the late afternoon? We don't know for sure.

Comment: A common response to this is "It's a date". As to your suggestions: A and B sound alright, C not so much, and D is a bit weird.

Answer (score 1):

In regular spoken dialogue, both A and B would be standard. Answer A implies that Lucy has agreed to meet at the library, and is now asking if they can meet at 6:30. Answer B is explicitly agreeing to meeting. I see no problem with either answer. Answer C doesn't sound quite right, but truthfully, answer D seems plausible as well.

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, but D implies *but not to meet you.* ;-)

Comment: It *definitely* could!

Answer (score 0):

All except "C" make sense.  "C" would make sense if it was "How about somewhere else," but, "How about meeting again," doesn't make sense in this context.